# Getting a 404 Error when trying to push react app to github

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I'm currently trying to push my react app to github but I keep receiving an error which says "Unexpected Application Error! 404 Not Found"

This is the link to my Github repository: https://github.com/anishkasam/spotify-stats-tracker

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I double checked my homepage link and scripts in my package.json file. Thanks in advance.